# Getting rid of nested observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have a method that relies on the data from two observables and the only way I have found to get it to work is by nesting the subscriptions of the observables and then calling the method inside the second subscribe method. This seems bad and there has to be a better way of accomplishing this can I get some help on a better way to do this?

Here is the controller:

```
meta$: Subscription;
meta: any;
data$: Subscription;
data: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.id = params['id']);
  this.getPageInfo();
}

private getPageInfo(): void {
  this.meta$ = this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}all/metadata`).subscribe(m => {
    this.meta = m;
    this.data$ = this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}/${this.id}`).subscribe(d => {
      this.data = d;
      this.setSelectedAttributes(); // <-- relies on this.meta and this.data
    }, err => console.error(err));
  }, err => console.error(err));
}

setSelectedAttributes(): void {
  const viewableAttributes = this.meta.columns.filter(c => !c.hidden && c.type === 'String');
  const selectedAttributes: Array<any> = [];
  for (const attr of viewableAttributes) {
    if (this.data[attr.field]) {
      selectedAttributes.push({name: attr.title, value: this.data[attr.field]});
    }
  }
  this.selectedAttributes = selectedAttributes;
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.data$.unsubscribe();
  this.meta$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this approach will work but you could have an array of subscriptions defined at scope, fill it with all your subscriptions and in `ngOnDestroy` check to see if the subscription is active, if it is `unsubscribe`.

Comment: @Bargros well my issue is not unsubscribing its the fact I have to nest them in the first place, that is what I am trying to avoid :)

Comment: use `pipe`, like so: `this.api.get('...').pipe( merge( getResult => this.api.get('...'))).subscribe( result => // do something )`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use just `concatMap` and then map the second response to contain also the response from the first response and maybe you won't even need to use any properties:

```
this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}all/metadata`).pipe(
  concatMap(response1 => this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}/${this.id}`)).pipe(
    map(response2 => [response1, response2])
  )
).subscribe(([response1, response2]) => {
  // Whatever here. You can set `this.meta = response1` etc...
});
```

Comment: why use concatMap when they seem to be independent? forkJoin seems to be the operator of choice since it executes in parralel, unless your goal is specifically to be NOT sending them both out in parrallel, even then, concat -> reduce is a cleaner and more scalable structure IMO

Answer (score 0):

Looks like those two api call can happen in parallel, use `forkJoin()` and `tap()` for side effect -> instance property assignment

```
private getPageInfo(): void {
 forkJoin(this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}all/metadata`),this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}/${this.id}`)).pipe(tap(([m,d])=>{
this.data$=d
this.meta$=m
this.setSelectedAttributes()
}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any subscription you could do it like this:

```
id$: Observable<number> = this.route.params.pipe(
    map(params => +params.id),
);


data$: Observable<Data> = this.id$.pipe(
  switchMap(id => this.api.get(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}/${this.id}`)),
);

export interface MetaData {
  columns: Atribute[];
}

export interface Attribute {
  hidden: boolean;
  type: string;
  title: string;
  field: string;
}

viewableAttributes$: Observable<Attribute[]> = this.api.get<MetaData>(`${Endpoints.LOCATIONS}all/metadata`).pipe(
  map(meta => meta.columns),
  filter(column => !column.hidden && c.type === 'String'),
);


export interface AttributeSelection {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

selectedAttributes$: Observable<AttributeSelection[]> = forkJoin([this.data$, this.viewableAttributes$]).pipe(
  map(([data, viewableAttributes]) => viewableAttributes.map(attr => ({ name: attr.title, value: data[attr.field]})).filter(attr => attr.value)),
);
```

You then only need to use async pipe on `selectedAttributes$`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `flatMap()`. This is the same as `mergeMap()` which is used to prevent nested subscriptions:

```
this.meta$ = this.api.get(...).map(
   flatMap((m) => {
      this.meta = m;
      ...
      return this.api.get(...)

   }),
   // You could also make another request if you need
   // flatMap((m) => {
   //    ...
   //    return this.api.get(...)
   // }),
).subscribe((d) => {
   this.data = d;
});
```

For more information: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Another tip:

If you want to destory everything in 1 variable use `takeUntil()` bound to an attribute to destory:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  request() {
     return this.apiService.get(...).pipe(
         takeUntil(this.destroy$)
     )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
  }
}
```